# Accessing context from this

Tags: this, nuxt.js

I have a middleware that exports `context.isMobile`. I can access it from layout like this:

```js
    layout (ctx) {
        if(ctx.isMobile) {
            return 'mobile'
        } else if (ctx.isDesktop) {
            return 'default'
        }
    },
```

...but I can't access the context from `data` or `computed`. How do I get the context there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the context via `this.$nuxt.context` like this:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    console.log(this.$nuxt.context)
    return { /*...*/ }
  },
  computed: {
    myProp() {
      console.log(this.$nuxt.context)  
      return 'foo'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this working but only while app initializes. after it disappears and my computed returns nothing. I intent to use this on static generate mode with nuxt. is that not possible